# Find general formula for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Having the following series: $$ - \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}- \frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{14}-\frac{1}{18}+\ldots$$
What is the easiest approach to find a general formula for this series?

Comment: An alternating series which would include a factor of $(-1)^{n}$ somewhere, the difference between each successive term's denominator is constant and equal to $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aaron write, it is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2\left(2n-1\right)}$$
 and this sum admit a closed form, in fact is the Taylor series of arctangent. So$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2\left(2n-1\right)}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2n-1}=-\frac{1}{8}\pi.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2(2n -1)}$$

It comes from the [Taylor Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of [$\arctan x$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RyLbbqW2k8) $$\arctan x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n-1}}{2n-1}$$

Let $x = 1$ and multiply it by $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It's the same thing I wrote.

Comment: I just gave him/her a hint, you came up with the complete answer. Just adding to my answer don't worry, as you said, I said it first.

Comment: I already specified in my answer that is the Taylor series of arctan. I find your hint useless. But I do not say this with polemical tone, it's only my opinion. No problem about it ;)

Comment: Useless, huh? I see.

Comment: However (+1) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Note that in each term of your series, denominate is form of a arithmetic sequence with common difference and numerator is alternate from -1 to 1. Therefore your series can be written in the form $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{4n-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The denominators are in an arithmetic progression:

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{4n-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:

- all numerators are $1$s;
- the difference between a denominator and the previous one is $4$;
- the sign is alternating.

With these considerations, you will find that the series can be expressed as
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2(2n - 1)}$$
since the first term is negative.